# Prove that the alternating harmonic series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that $\sum_1^{\propto} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} $ is convergent.

I came across this proof which shows that the sequence of partial sums $(s_n)$ is bounded. It goes like this:
$0 \leq (s_{2n}) \leq (s_{2n+1}) \leq 1$. $(s_{2n})$ is monotonically increasing, and $(s_{2n+1}) $ is monotonically decreasing. So, we have that both these subsequences are convergent. How can we conclude from this that $(s_n)$ converges, i.e how can we conclude that both the above subsequences converge to the same limit? They can converge to different limits? No? Please tell me why. Thank you

Comment: The limit of both subsequences has to be the same since $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|=0.$$

Comment: and this is not special about the alternating harmonic series: Foe every $\sum (-1)^na_n$ where $a_n$ is monotonic decreasing to $0$, we find by the same argument that the series converges (Leibniz criterion)

Comment: Although it doesn't answer ,FYKI  this sequence converges to $\ln 2$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio How does that suggest that the partial sum subsequences converge to the same limit? I didn't quite understand this.

Comment: @Adienl: what is $s_{2n+1}-s_{2n}$? If $s_{2n+1}\to L'$, $s_{2n}\to L''$ and the previous difference converges to zero, then $L'=L''$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That does it. :) Thank you so much.

Comment: the result should be $$\ln(2)$$